# Invalid config file for xmr-stack-amd

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining

I am using Linux Mint and my processor is AMD A10-7860K Radeon R7 CPU. I have installed xmr-stack-amd and have got to the stage where I can start it. However, I have not been able to successfully edit the config.txt file.

It would be helpful to be pointed to an example config file which I could use as a basis. Is there one available?

Also the current error I am getting is "Invalid config file. Missing value "daemon_mode"." What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

From the title of your post, specifically the part where it says "xmr-stak-amd" leads me to believe that you are trying to use an AMD GPU miner instead of xmr-stak-cpu.

The hardware you posted: "AMD A10-7860K Radeon R7 CPU" is a CPU

You will need to use xmr-stak-cpu: https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu
I know it says -amd, but thats actually referring to GPUs, AMD makes both, but that miner you're trying to use is not meant for CPUs